# Replace null with last known value in Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery

In Power Query, I am trying to create a custom column that replaces any null values with the last known value in that column. i.e.

[image]

What would the code be for this new column in M?

BTW - While I believe that this would be easier in Power Pivot, I have already build my data model (and dashboard) based off the column names. Changing the data model would cause all my charts, tables and metrics to be rebuilt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Query Editor, click on the column, go to the Transform tab, and choose Fill | Down. It will generate something like `= Table.FillDown(Table,{"Amount"})`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much for the nice easy fix.